# Populating a cell in a dataGrid with multiple values seperated by commas - Flex

Tags: xml, apache-flex, file, datagrid, populate

I have an XML file with this data.

```
<resultSet> 
<MerchandiseAssortmentCategory>
                                <merchandiseAssortmentCategoryId>275</merchandiseAssortmentCategoryId>
                                <merchandiseAssortmentCategoryName>D21 Plywood</merchandiseAssortmentCategoryName>
                                <merchandiseSubordinateClasses>
                                                <merchandiseSubordinateClass>
                                                                <merchandiseSubordinateClassNumber>2</merchandiseSubordinateClassNumber>
                                                                <merchandiseSubordinateClassDescription>SHEATHING</merchandiseSubordinateClassDescription>
                                                </merchandiseSubordinateClass>
                                                <merchandiseSubordinateClass>
                                                                <merchandiseSubordinateClassNumber>3</merchandiseSubordinateClassNumber>
                                                                <merchandiseSubordinateClassDescription>WAFERBOARD</merchandiseSubordinateClassDescription>
                                                </merchandiseSubordinateClass>
                                                <merchandiseSubordinateClass>
                                                                <merchandiseSubordinateClassNumber>4</merchandiseSubordinateClassNumber>
                                                                <merchandiseSubordinateClassDescription>SANDED</merchandiseSubordinateClassDescription>
                                                </merchandiseSubordinateClass>
                                </merchandiseSubordinateClasses>
</MerchandiseAssortmentCategory>
</resultSet>
```

I need to populate a data grid with the merchandiseAssortmentCategoryName and all its merchandiseSubordinateClassNumber(s) seperated with commas in the same row.

the categoryList is which is the dataprovider for the dataGrid is defined as follows :

```
this.categoryList= evt.result.resultSet.MerchandiseAssortmentCategory;
```

and this is how the dataGrid is defined

```
<mx:DataGrid x="466" y="73" width="192" height="225" 
        dataProvider="{categoryList}" 
        verticalScrollPolicy="on" 
        id="categories"
        rowCount="10" enabled="true">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Category name" dataField="merchandiseAssortmentCategoryName"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Subclasses" dataField="merchandiseSubordinateClasses.merchandiseSubordinateClass.merchandiseSubordinateClassNumber"/>

            </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
```

When i run this, only the category name is filled. the subordinateclass number is just blank. Help out with this. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to have to write a labelFunction to return the comma separated list you want displayed in the column.

Read these docs on creating a [custom label function](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dpcontrols_2.html).  Here are some relevant details:

[Start Quote]

You can pass a label function to the List control to provide logic that determines the text that appears in the control. The label function must have the following signature:

```
labelFunction(item:Object):String
```

The item parameter passed in by the Label control contains the list item object. The function must return the string to display in the List control.

Note: Most subclasses of ListBase also take a labelFunction property with the signature described above. For the DataGrid and DataGridColumn controls, the method signature is labelFunction(item:Object, dataField:DataGridColumn):String, where item contains the DataGrid item object, and dataField specifies the DataGrid column.

....

```
<mx:Script><![CDATA[
    public function myLabelFunc(item:Object):String {
        return item.data + ", " + item.label; 
    }
]]></mx:Script>
```

[End Quote]

The item object parameter is the element of the dataProvider you want to generate a label for.

You can specify the labelFunction property on the class in question:

```
<mx:DataGridColumn labelFunction="myLabelFunc" />
```

You can also do the same thing with a custom itemRenderer.

Comment: You *can* do the same thing with a custom itemRenderer, but the labelFunction is the best way to go for String based data conversions.

Comment: how do i write the labelFunction ?

Comment: See the section on using a label Function: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dpcontrols_2.html .  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yeah the labelFunction makes sense...but how would I even access the field. Its in a nested XML and a dataGrid's dataField doesn't parse through :( Any help with that would be much appreciated

Comment: The "Object" passed into the labelFunction will be your XML object.  Run through in debug mode and use that to figure out how to drill down into the XML structure.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

1. Make a custom itemRenderer for the Subclasses column in the DataGrid.
2. Override the `set data` method to go through all of your subclasses and build the comma delimited string.
3. Set the value of the itemRenderer's label to your comma delimited string.